# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable -1

Tags: python-3.x

I a new to object oriented programming. I was trying to create a class that can find distance between two points. I passed points as tuples as coordinates.  I wrote this code but its showing error.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1= coor1
        self.coor2= coor2
    def distance(self):
        print(((self.coor1[0]-self.coor2[0])**2(self.coor1[1]-self.coor2[1])**2)**0.5)
    def slope (self):
        print((self.coor2[1]-self.coor1[1])/(self.coor2[0]-self.coor1[0]))
coordinate1 = (3,2)
coordinate2 = (8,10)

li = Line(coordinate1,coordinate2)
li.distance()
```

I know this could be resolved using tuple unpacking but I want to know why my code is not working?

Comment: You perhaps missed a `+` in `**2(self.coor1[1]` So it will be `print(((self.coor1[0]-self.coor2[0])**2+(self.coor1[1]-self.coor2[1])**2)**0.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `distance` you wrote `2(self.coor1[1]-self.coor2[1])` which asks python to execute the `__call__` method of an object(2) of class int. You just have to add another addition/subtraction sign after 2.

In the example I'm assuming you want to add.

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self,coor1,coor2):
        self.coor1= coor1
        self.coor2= coor2
    def distance(self):
        print(((self.coor1[0]-self.coor2[0])**2+(self.coor1[1]-self.coor2[1])**2)**0.5)
    def slope (self):
        print((self.coor2[1]-self.coor1[1])/(self.coor2[0]-self.coor1[0]))
coordinate1 = (3,2)
coordinate2 = (8,10)

li = Line(coordinate1,coordinate2)
li.distance()
```